# Share a socks proxy on LAN

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, socks-proxy, socks5

I have socks proxy running on port 1080. I want other people on LAN to use this proxy. How can I do that?

One way is that the client can run this command and then use proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 on his computer:

```
ssh -L 1080:127.0.0.1:1080 myusername@myipaddress
```

But, I dont want to use ssh because that requires me to give my password to others.

Comment: why do you run the proxy on 127.0.0.1 if it shall be used from the outside? bind it to your lan address instead.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: It depends on the proxy server you are using.. set it to bind to all interfaces instead of just localhost.

Comment: The proxy is run using ssh -D option. Dynamic port forwarding..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See your proxys configuration file. Usually there should be an option "bind". Set that to your lan accessable ip address or even to any address (0.0.0.0).

To be sure you should check the proxys documentation on how to actually bind to addresses or interfaces.

After binding to the lan ip (and maybe configuring the firewall to allow access) anyone on the lan should be able to use your computer as proxy.

Comment: btw: you could provide some more information on the proxy software you use. the name would be a good start ;)

Comment: That proxy is running using "ssh -D"

Comment: ok. thats simple. ssh -D takes a bind address parameter plus port. Just use ssh -D <your_lan_address>:<port>. i guess if no bind address is given it defaults to 127.0.0.1

Comment: But, I dont want others to have access to my files. I dont want to give them password of my account. I have mentioned this point in my question

Comment: you dont have to give away your password. once the proxy is running anyone can connect to the port and the ssh proxy is forwarding the traffic. `ssh -D <your_ip>:1080 your_user@your_machine` with this command your machine is acting as socks proxy on port 1080 to anyone in the lan.